# LAT of sboxes, sum of coloms and rows

Tags: s-boxes, linear-cryptanalysis

let we have sbox s: Vn -> Vn.

If we make LAT table for s, fix any row and get a sum by columns, that sum would be $+-2^{n-1}$.

And vice versa, if we fix any column and get a sum by rows, that sum would be $+-2^{n-1}$ too. Why is it so?

Element in "a" row, "b" column of LAT is $#{<a, x>=<b,s(x)>} - 2^{n-1}$. Where <*,*> is scalar product.

Sum is a sum of integers that are in one matrix column/ one matrix row.

Comment: Is this a test/homework question? It's a favourite property to check/show in lecture notes. The fact you write Vn without even defining it made me think so.

Comment: I'm not a student, and I'm trying to figure it out on my own, found this question in lcd tutorial.

Comment: Vn is space of row vectors of length n over the field GF(2), I thught I shouldn't write that in cryptography section

Comment: Sum over what? Integers? Define the LAT expression at each entry of the matrix. There are centred and uncentred versions. We are not mind readers.

Comment: please note it is customary to upvote/accept nice answers. I am sorry if I was harsh before but trying to improve your statement of the question and see exactly which formulation you were using. You could use the answer as a guide to how properly edit your formulas using Latex in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a row/column of LAT correspond to a component function of the S-box/its inverse (a linear combination of outputs). So, let's derive the value of the sum of all Walsh coefficients of any Boolean function.

I will use this definition of Walsh transform. The results for others can be adapted easily.

$$W_f(a) = \sum_{x\in F_n} (-1)^{\langle a, x\rangle + f(x)},$$
$$\sum_{a \in F_n}W_f(a) = \sum_{a \in F_n}\sum_{x\in F_n} (-1)^{\langle a, x\rangle + f(x)} = \sum_{x\in F_n}\big((-1)^{f(x)}\sum_{a \in F_n}(-1)^{\langle a, x\rangle}\big).$$
The inner sum is equal to zero whenever $x\ne 0$ (linear functions are balanced), and is equal to $2^n$ when $x=0$. We get
$$\sum_{a \in F_n}W_f(a) = 2^n\cdot (-1)^{f(0)}.$$

This you can observe e.g. on SageMath's `BooleanFunction.walsh_hadamard_transform`.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what is needed!